# jquery set html from select value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have not used jquery much yet and not very familiar with it.

Trying to do the below:

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#day').change (function () 
    {
```

//next to lines work here but not if placed after $.get

```
        var day =  $('#day').val() ;

    $("#test").html(day);

        $.get('http://www.sharingizcaring.com/schedule/menutest.php', { day: $('#day').val() },      
        function(data) 
        {
          $("#test").html( data );
         });
    });    
});
```

Setting the .html to blah blah works.. But if I switch actions to use the value of the select item #day

day is a `<select>` tag.

Also the code works correctly above the $.get() function.

It does not work.

Comment: The code you're using to get the `#day` value is quite correct syntactically.  What exactly is `#day`?  An `<input>` or `<textarea>` presumably?  What's in it (i.e., what is its value)?

Comment: #day is a <select> I moved the code above the $.get and it works. So something to do with the $.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily, I would expect that you would set the value on return to something you got back from the server.  To do that you need to add a parameter to your callback function and reference the value on it.  I'm going to assume that your menutest method returns HTML containing the "new" day input.

```
$.get('http://www.sharingizcaring.com/schedule/menutest.php',
      { day: $('#day').val()  },      
      function(data) {
          $("#test").html( data );
      }
);
```

Comment: day is a <select> so it just gets the value of that.. menutest.php doesn't do anything yet but that might be part of my problem

Comment: You might want to show a bigger code snippet.  The value of the select shouldn't be different depending on where you grab the value.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the problem with the url you are sending a request to. I think it should be the same domain s the page, otherwise it wont work. Also, try using Firebug to see if requests get sent and what is returned. Firebug is realy helpfull.

Comment: Hhmm thanks I tried that out and ended up the script runs perfect in firefox just not chrome... I will start a new question.